# Shuffle an array by sorting in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, shuffle

I'm currently reading CRLS and implementing the algorithms in javascript.

In section 5.3 - Permute by sorting, I felt like a morron while trying to come up with an efficient implementation of the simple algorithm. Here is the pseudo-code:
[image: shuffle by sorting]

Here is my implementation

```
Array.prototype.sortShuffle = function () {
    const LENGTH = this.length;
    const CUBE = Math.pow(LENGTH, 3);

    let P = this
        .map((e, i) => {
            return {v: Math.floor(Math.random() * CUBE), e: e}
        })
        .sort((e1, e2) => e1.v > e2.v);

    P.forEach((e, i) => this[i] = e.e);
}
```

I resorted to this sad solution because the native Array.prototype.sort doesn't provide the indexes in the comparator, A.sort((e1, e2, i1, i2) => ...) could have done the trick.

Can anyone please provide a more efficient solution (without implementing the sorting function above all)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is actually well done, but could just use some style improvements:

```
Array.prototype.sortShuffle = function () {
    const nCubed = Math.pow(this.length, 3);

    this.map(v => ({ k: Math.random() * nCubed, v }))
        .sort(({ k: k1 }, { k: k2 }) => k1 - k2)
        .forEach(({ v }, i) => this[i] = v);
};
```

In particular, you can use [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring), as well as removing some unnecessary variables. Also, you don't need to use `Math.floor`, because floating point numbers will work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the other array as "tuples" which makes for code that's a *little* cleaner.

```
Array.prototype.sortShuffle = function () {
  return this.map(v => [Math.random() * this.length ** 3, v])
             .sort(([k1,v1],[k2,v2]) => k1 - k2)
             .map(([k, v]) => v);
}
```

In terms of speed - you're better off using [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) or another `O(n)` algorithm.

Note that you had a mistake in your implementation as sort expects the comparator function to return a positive or negative number (rather than just a boolean).